# How do I disable %%cython within Python Jupyter Notebook Script?

Tags: python-3.x, cythonize

I'm creating an NLP related Jupyter notebook, hopefully to be released for public use. I'm using Cython magic commands for some code to increase speed, using "%%cython" at the beginning of some cells. 
What I want to do is make the use of such cython magic commands (and related cython commands, cdef etc) a configureable parameter that users can specify in an earlier cell.

I've tried conditionals to allow users to "turn off" cython, however these don't seem to work as "%% cython" needs to be listed on the first line of the cell.

Here's the code:

```
%%cython

import numpy as np # access to Numpy from Python layer
import math

        cdef:
            function defn here
```

Here's my attempt at a solution:

Configuration Cell

```
turn_on_cython = True # May be changed by user to false
```

Subsequent Cell

```
if (turn_on_cython == True):
   %%cython
```

(doesn't work)